# Making a plural rails "resources" url into singular

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have in my routes.rb file

```
resources :shops
```

which I want, since I want to separate index and show routes, but this leads to a /shops/ url

I'd actually like it to make to /shop - what's the easiest way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want them all to be `/shop` `shop/1` etc. then do:

```
resources :shops, path: "shop"
```

Otherwise maybe you can do

```
resources :shops, except: :show
# then
resources :shops, only: :show, path: "shop"
# or
get "shop/:id", to: "shops#show", as: :shop
```